# invalid object name 'dbo.Fruit' error in edit method of viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am using viewmodel which is a combination of Fruit and Category table, and its name is FruitCatergory(viewmodel). i can add and retreive the data of two columns successfully. the problem is when i click the edit link , it is displaying error
**{"Invalid object name 'dbo.FruitCatergory'."}**

Fruit

- FruitId (PK)
- FruitName
- ReleasedDate
- CategoryId (FK)

Category

- CategoryId (PK)
- CategoryName

i want to only edit the rows which's releasedDate is null

```
// GET: FrutiCategorys/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        FruitCategory fruitCategory = db.Fruit.Find(id);
        // FruitCategory fruitCategory  = (from c in db.Category join f in db.Fruit on c.CategoryId equals f.CategoryId where (f.ReleasedDate == null) select e).FirstOrDefault( s => s.FruitId.Equals(id));
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.RankId = new SelectList(db.Category, "CategoryId", "CategoryName", FrutiCategory.CategoryId);

        return View(frutiCategory);
    }
```

Comment: check whether your Edit View has @model ProjName.Models.FruitCategory,because you are passing fruitCategory to view. Also check the spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add your post action to the question, so it's hard to say what's going on with the specific error your question is about. However, based on what's going on in your get action, I can take a guess.

`FruitCategory`, as you say, is a view model, which means it's not persisted. To new it up, you need to map over values from `Fruit` and `Category`, respectively, not simply cast it. For example:

```
var fruit = db.Fruit.Include('Category').SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
if (fruit == null || fruit.Category == null)
{
    return new HttpNotFoundResult(); 
}

var model = new FruitCategory
{
    FruitName = fruit.FruitName,
    ...
    CategoryName = fruit.Category.CategoryName,
    ...
};

return View(model);
```

Likewise, in your post action, you cannot simply save `FruitCategory` as a `Fruit`, but rather, you need to map the values back on to an instance from the database:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var fruit = db.Fruit.Include('Category').SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
    if (fruit == null)
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult(); 
    }

    fruit.FruitName = model.FruitName;
    ...
    fruit.Category.CategoryName = model.CategoryName;
    ...

    db.Entry(fruit).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}

return View(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the binding table for your class FrutiCategory? If not, it will consider the class name as the table name.

Also... Have you checked this spelling mistake?

```
return View(frutiCategory);
```